# Test driver package practicalmeteor:mocha missing `runTests` export

Tags: testing, meteor, mocha.js

I've just updated to meteor 1.3 and have been trying to use mocha for testing. I haven't used it before, so I'm not sure if I'm implementing it wrong, but  I get the error

```
Test driver package practicalmeteor:mocha missing `runTests` export
```

in the chrome debug window when I run my app with

```
meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha
```

I don't think the issue is with my tests, since the crash is happening as the app is starting. I do get the confirmation in the cmd that my app is running

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2.1.0_7 practicalmeteor:mocha package.
Try to update practicalmeteor:mocha package

```
meteor add practicalmeteor:mocha@2.1.1-rc.1
```